# Is ''If I knew, I would have told you" a correct use of conditionals

Tags: conditionals

I was wondering if one could use if + past simple / would + have + past participle.

Comment: This is correct.  It is a very good example of usage of conditionals.

Comment: This sounds weird to me. I would say either "If I knew, I would tell you" or "If I had known, I would have told you." Searching the OP's sentence returns a scholarly paper on nonstandard conditionals: doi:10.2478/rjes-2014-0001 and a few other discussions of the unidiomatic nature of this construction.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you most definitely could.

> *if* + **past** simple / *would* + have + **past** participle.

You have two verbs in the past form (to know and to tell). Therefore, the tense is consistent in the context.

You also begin with a dependent *if* clause, which is correct. The usage of the auxiliary *would* in the independent clause is obviously appropriate here as you're using it is a conditional verb.

On another note, ***would*** can be replaced with *could* and *might*. It will change the meaning, but it's something to keep note of because it is still grammatically correct.